# Error in an XML file in my android project

Tags: android

this is my first android project and i cant debug this training app [Building a Simple User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)

when i debug it for run i see this :

> Error in an XML file: aborting build.

(for android:hint="@string/edit_message" /> )

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you create a string with name edit_message inside strings.xml?

Comment: you are also missing `/>` at the end of button. Also you should have a string named `edit_message` defined in strings.xml

Comment: You can find the complete layout at this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close `<LinearLayout>` and `<Button>` tags. Even StackOverflow syntax highligting suggests this. Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a string named "edit_message".

If, yes, why in your code you don't close the first "LinearLayout" with this ">"